# How can I fix a stretched display with AMD graphics card after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics

After upgrading to 16.04, my display is stretched. I have an AMD cedar card, so I guess this is part of the Ubuntu-AMD problem (of which I wasn't aware before upgrading). What can I do to get normal proportions again?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved after removing fglrx, that had somehow survived a previous purging attempt since the package manager hung up on another package (gcc-doc) and didn't come to the purging command.